# Is there any automatic way to discover epsg code and proj4 to geojson file in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers, geojson, epsg

I have a project to load some geojson files and then plot then in a openlayers map. I was doing fine with a sample file from Blumenau/Santa Catarina/Brazil (city/state/country) but when I uploaded new files from Brazil cities, they seen displaced in map.

Is there any way to automatic define proj4 params and epsg code when uploading files to my website? Actually, the page only upload files and define it by a new name, without alter it data.
When I tried to upload Santo Andre/Sao Paulo/Brazil data, it is ploted in other state from Brazil, but with Santo Andre city format.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>

proj4.defs('EPSG:32722', '+proj=utm +zone=22 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs ');
ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);

{% load static %}

var suscetibilidadeDeslizamento = new ol.layer.Vector({
                                      source: new ol.source.Vector({
                                        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:32722'}),
                                        url: '{% static deslizamento %}'
                                      }),
                                      style: style,
                                      opacity: 0.3
                                    });
var map = new ol.Map({
                          target: 'map',
                          layers: [

                            new ol.layer.Tile({
                                source: new ol.source.OSM()
                              }),
                                    suscetibilidadeDeslizamento

                          ],
                          view: new ol.View({
                            center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-49, -27]),
                            zoom: 5
                          })
                        });
```

Here is Blumenau data ploted. Data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tiagoferneda/files/master/SuscetibilidadeInundacaoBlumenau.json
[image: Blumenau data]

Here is Santo Andre data ploted, over Terra Boa city, far from correct location. Data: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tiagoferneda/files/master/SuscetibilidadeInundacaoSantoAndre.json
[image: Santo Andre data]

Comment: The GeoJSON specification http://wiki.geojson.org/GeoJSON_draft_version_6 allows a CRS to be specified (which OpenLayers should understand) but those example don't include one.  Without that you would need to know the UTM zone (or the longitude so you could calculate the zone) of each city.  Santo Andre is exactly 6 degrees east of Terra Boa so in zone 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading the CRS of your JSON before to create the `ol.layer.Vector` and then adding the corresponding proj4 params.

You should take a look at [this OpenLayers example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/reprojection-by-code.html) where it loads proj4 params dynamically from EPSG.io

Comment: In this case the GeoJSONs don't specify a CRS.

Comment: @Mike Oh you're right I missed that. The [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-4) says the coordinates must be in WGS 84 but in this case according to the code Santo Andre data should be in EPSG:32722.  did you try load the data in QGIS specifying that CRS? Maybe there is something wrong with the coords.

Comment: Blumenau is in zone 22 and data is EPSG:32722 but Santo Andre is in zone 23 and data is  EPSG:32723 but is being treated as EPSG:32722 and displayed 6 degree west of where it should be.  But for other cities I'm not sure if Brazil strictly follows UTM zone boundaries or if, like Spain, it is done by province.